# Would a straight line between two points on a sinusoidal map be the same as the geodesic between those points on a sphere's surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, coordinate-systems, geodesic, cartography

Recently I've been trying to find the relationship between a Mercator map ( whose coordinates I'll express with x and y ) and the surface of a sphere such as a globe ( whose coordinates I'll express with λ and φ). I figured that $$[x, y] = [λcos(φ), φ]$$ I then calculated the metric tensor of this vector (g<sub>λφ</sub>) and I noticed the g<sub>11</sub> = $(λ*sin(φ))^2 + 1$ At first I got confused because latitude distances should be equal on a Mercator and a globe, but then I realized that the term being influenced by longitude is a result of line distortion on sinusoidal maps - which means my original equation refers not to a sphere's surface, but a sinusoidal projection! Even so, I still feel like I'm onto something. Seeing as my original goal was to be able to calculate geodesics on a sphere and convert them to a Mercator projection, I would like to know if a geodesic on a sinusoidal is the same as that on a globe, because if so, I would have achieved this goal, and all this math would have not been a waste of time.

Comment: Not sure I understand in detail, but the answer to the question _in the title_ appears to be _no_: There is a unique line segment between two points of a plane region (such as a sinusoidal map), but multiple geodesics join pairs of antipodal points on a globe; great circles are not generally sent to lines in a plane map. <> The body question appears to be different, however: _straight line_ in the title seems to be replaced by _geodesic on the sinusoidal_ [projection]. <> Could you perhaps reword to separate the question from your own thoughts, and to align the title and question body?