# What is the manifold formula for coordinates on a globe, in relation to Cartesian/Mercator coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, geodesic, cartography

For context, I am attempting to find a method of converting Mercator projections to a globe, as to find the geodesic. Initially I thought Mercator longitude x and latitude y could be converted to coordinates of a globe, longitude λ and latitude φ with the equation $$[x, y] = [λcos(φ), φ]$$ However, when I calculated the metric tensor I found that the latitude vector stretched not by a factor of 1 (which is expected of a globe) but rather, by a variable factor depending on longitude ($(λsin(φ))^2+1$), which led to me figuring out that my original equation referred not to a sphere's surface, but to a sinusoidal map projection. That does bid the question, though: if not $[λcos(φ), φ]$, then what vector does refer to the manifold of a sphere's surface?

P.S. I'm treating Mercator coordinates as Cartesian coordinates, |x| < 180 and |y| < 90.

Comment: Why not look up mercator projection and its inverse the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function in wikipedia?

Comment: Remember that the whole point of the Mercator projection is that lines of longitude map to lines of longitude (which you have) *and* it is conformally equivalent to the usual metric. I find your discussion confusing: In the usual metric, the *longitude* vector has length $1$. Are you confusing latitude and longitude?

Comment: How does this question differ from [Would a straight line between two points on a sinusoidal map be the same as the geodesic between those points on a sphere's surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791181/139123) When you post two questions so closely related, I recommend that one question should refer to the other (**in the question itself**, not in comments) so that people are not duplicating stuff that was written in response to the other question.

Comment: In a Mercator projection, you never reach the north or south pole no matter how far you travel on the map. It makes no sense to me that you would treat Mercator coordinates as Cartesian coordinates and then say that $|y|<90$. The equation $[x, y] = [\lambda\cos(\varphi),\varphi]$ **does** give you a projection to Cartesian coordinates $|x| \leq 180$ and $|y| \leq 90$, but it is not a Mercator projection.